# How to I authenticate against a private PPA on LaunchPad?

Tags: apt, ppa, authentication, launchpad

I'm the maintainer of a private PPA on LaunchPad. Still, I cannot figure out how to properly authenticate against it. I have a URL starting with

```
 https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/...
```

in my `sources.list`, but running `apt-get update` results in

```
W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/...: 401  Authorization Required
```

Where do I need to enter my credentials? As part of `sources.list` like

```
https://username:password@private-ppa.launchpad.net/...
```

? If so, which `username` and `password` are these? Is it the username I use to login to the LaunchPad web interface? But that would be my Ubuntu One email address, not a username. Also for the password, which one sould I use? If I enter the PPA's URL directly in the browser I get a prompt saying

```
A username and password are being requested by https://private-ppa.launchpad.net. The site says: "Token Required"
```

What token is that message referring to?

**Edit:** Could it be that I'm affected by the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/860273? If so, how do I generate an access token?

Answer (score 5):

I've found it out:

1. Go to the PPA's page.
2. Click on *Manage access* in the top right corner.
3. Click on *Add access* in the top left corner.
4. Enter the name of a person (yourself) or a team (you're a member of), click *Add* at the end of the row.
5. Go back to the PPA's page.
6. Expand the *Technical details about this PPA* section which now includes the credentials in the URLs.

Comment: Note that if you still can't see your credential on the ppa page (step 6) after being granted access in step 4, try to visit the "View your private PPA subscriptions" link on your launchpad account page (https://launchpad.net/~YOURACCOUNT/+archivesubscriptions) and click on the view button on the right, you will find those info there.